# Upgraded from 14.0 to 16.04. Boot failure

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, kernel

I recently upgraded my dedicated server to **ubuntu 16.04 LTS** (for somes reasons).
I don't know why, but when I started my server, nothing happened (no ping response).

With my host, I can boot on a live cd image (ubuntu 12.04) to recorvery my server.
So I mounted my partitions to do a chroot session and I navigated to my /var/log folder. In this folder, there is no news logs (like "boot.log" or "syslog" written when I start my server with Ubuntu 16.04. It's like the server don't boot. Maybe a Grub Config Bug ?

Ps: I recently had a problem with my image "/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic" (image was missing when I tried to apt-get -f upgrade)  but I reinstalled a new one with apt-get, 
My kernel version :

```
Linux 62-210-243-90 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is my Grub configuration :

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=ttyS1,9600 BOOTIF=01-e8-9a-8f-22-d9-61"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Thanks for your help, I know there is not enought informations, I don't know what's happening (And sorry for my bad english, I'm french).

Comment: As it says: Run `sudo update-grub` from the terminal of a live disk.

Comment: Ok, It found the kernel :  `root@62-210-243-90:/boot# sudo update-grub
sudo: impossible de déterminer le nom de l'hôte 62-210-243-90
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done `

Comment: Reboot and see if it boots properly or not from the disk, not the live disk.

Comment: It can't boot. No ping response from the server. I reboot with the livecd

Comment: There is no new logs. I'm in chroot again

Comment: My currently kernel version is 3.13.0-32 and I installed kernel version 4.4.0-47. I tried to install linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic with apt but it couldn't  find linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic package